# Python path is not recognized after adding a new variable under environment variables, picture provided

Tags: python, cmd.exe

> `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

My Python folder is directly in `C:\python34`.

Please look at the picture:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In **Environment Variables**, make sure that you have `:C:\python34:` in your `PATH` variable.